# Perform action on object in the RxJava chain during onDispose

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have an RxJava chain like so:

```
Single.timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .map { createMyObject() }
    .doOnDispose {
         // how to access MyObject here? I want to call:
         myObject.dismiss()
    }
    .subscribe { myObject ->
        // do something with myObject
    }
```

However, `.doOnDispose` expects an `Action` instead of a `Consumer` so I can't access the previously mapped `myObject` in it.

What I am doing for now is having an external nullable variable outside the Rx chain to hold the object:

```
var myObject: MyObject? = null
Single.timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .map { 
         myObject = createMyObject() 
         return@map myObject
    }
    .doOnDispose {
         myObject?.dismiss()
    }
    .subscribe { myObject ->
        // do something with myObject
    }
```

But I don't like the idea of exposing it outside the chain. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `Single.using` to properly handle the the dispose operation when appropriate

something like

```
Single.using({createMyObject()}, {something(it)}, {it.dismiss}).subscribe{...}
```

see http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/using.html